# How can I write the unit cost function of this nesting production function

Tags: microeconomics

Assume that there is a production function as follow:

$$h=\left\{ \left[ \sum_{j=1}^N{s_{j}^{\mu}} \right] ^{\frac{1}{\mu}} \right\} ^{\beta}l^{1-\beta}$$

The price of $s_j$ is $p_j$ and the wage of $l$ is $w_l$. $h$ is the final good and $\mu ,\beta ,N$ are parameters. I tried use Lagrange method to calculate cost function but I failed. How to solve this kind of production function's cost function?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the cost minimization problem explicitly, but it might be easier to consider the similarity with the utility maximising consumer problem and first look at the dual utility maxmisation problem.

If so, the utility (output) maximisation problem takes the form:
$$
\max_{s_j, \ell} \left(\left(\sum_{j= 1}^N s_j^\mu\right)^{1/\mu}\right)^\beta \ell^{1 - \beta} \text{ s.t. } \sum_j p_j s_j + w \ell = m.
$$
This utility function is weakly separable, so we can use two stage budgetting where in the second stage one optimally chooses $s_1, \ldots, s_N$ given the expenditures on these goods. Let $z = \sum_{j} p_j s_j$ be the expenditure on the goods $s_j$. Then the second stage can be written as:
$$
\max_{s_j} \left(\sum_{j = 1}^N s_j^\mu\right)^{1/\mu} \text{ s.t. } \sum_j p_j s_j = z.
$$
This production function is a standard CES. So the indirect utility function takes the form (double check):
$$
\left(\sum_{j = 1}^N s_j^\mu\right)^{1/\mu}= \underbrace{\left(\sum_j p_{j}^{1 - \mu}\right)^{1/(\mu - 1)}}_{=P} z.
$$
Substituting into the utility function gives the first stage problem:
$$
\max_{z, \ell}  (Pz)^\beta \ell^{1-\beta} \text{ s.t. } z + y = m
$$
Now, reparametrize $x = P z$ and $p = 1/P$ to obtain the following problem:
$$
\max_{z, \ell}  (x)^\beta \ell^{1-\beta} \text{ s.t. } px + w \ell = m
$$
This is a standard Cobb-Douglass utility maximisation problem, so the indirect utility is (double check):
$$
v(p,w,m) = \beta^\beta (1-\beta)^{1-\beta} \left(1/p\right)^{\beta} \left(1/w\right)^{1-\beta} m
$$
Given this, we can subsitute out $p= 1/P$ to get:
$$
v(p, w, m) = \beta^\beta (1-\beta)^{1-\beta} \left(\sum_j p_j^{1 - \mu}\right)^{\beta/(\mu - 1)} \left(1/w\right)^{1-\beta} m
$$
This gives the indirect utility function. The expenditure (cost) function can be obtained by inverting this with respect to $m$:
$$
c(p,w, y) = \left(1/\beta\right)^\beta \left(1/(1-\beta)\right)^{1-\beta} \left(\sum_j p_j^{1-\mu}\right)^{-\beta/(\mu - 1)} \left(w\right)^{1-\beta} y.
$$
Note that this is linear in $y$ as the production function is homogeneous of degree 1.